# How can I get an error message if the update of mySQL database failed?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a simple error message, when the update of my SQL database failed.

```
foreach($animals as $row) {

   $cat = "234";

   $sql = "UPDATE animals set cat2 = ?  WHERE cat1 = ?";
   $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute(array($cat,$cat));                               
}

if ($q->execute(array($cat,$cat)))
{
echo "success";
}
else
{
echo "failure";
}
```

But even if the update failed and nothing is updated, I get the message: success.

Comment: execute statement `$q->execute(array($cat,$cat))`  two times in your code and why you put your update qyery inside  foreach loop???

Comment: It's not an error if no rows match the condition.

Comment: if no rows match the condition, I will get the message: success